# Conditional Python Polars cum_sum over a group, is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to create a column that is a cumulative sum over a group column but the cumulative sum only happens when the 'days' column meets a certain condition. I have come up with what I regard as a "duct tape" solution, there must be a more elegant way.

```
import polars as pl

# Create a DataFrame with literal values
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "days": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1],
    "amount": [100, 200, 150, 300, 250, 180, 220, 280, 210, 320,21,456,111],
    "group": ["A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A","C","B","B"]
})

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

#My duct tape solution
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("days") > 2)
        .then(pl.col("amount"))
        .otherwise(0).alias("3+days_amount")
                  )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("3+days_amount").cum_sum().over("group").alias("group_cumsum")
    )
)

print(df)

shape: (13, 3)
┌──────┬────────┬───────┐
│ days ┆ amount ┆ group │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ str   │
╞══════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 100    ┆ A     │
│ 1    ┆ 200    ┆ B     │
│ 2    ┆ 150    ┆ A     │
│ 3    ┆ 300    ┆ C     │
│ 4    ┆ 250    ┆ B     │
│ …    ┆ …      ┆ …     │
│ 3    ┆ 210    ┆ C     │
│ 4    ┆ 320    ┆ A     │
│ 6    ┆ 21     ┆ C     │
│ 7    ┆ 456    ┆ B     │
│ 1    ┆ 111    ┆ B     │
└──────┴────────┴───────┘
shape: (13, 5)
┌──────┬────────┬───────┬───────────────┬──────────────┐
│ days ┆ amount ┆ group ┆ 3+days_amount ┆ group_cumsum │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---           ┆ ---          │
│ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ str   ┆ i64           ┆ i64          │
╞══════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 100    ┆ A     ┆ 0             ┆ 0            │
│ 1    ┆ 200    ┆ B     ┆ 0             ┆ 0            │
│ 2    ┆ 150    ┆ A     ┆ 0             ┆ 0            │
│ 3    ┆ 300    ┆ C     ┆ 300           ┆ 300          │
│ 4    ┆ 250    ┆ B     ┆ 250           ┆ 250          │
│ …    ┆ …      ┆ …     ┆ …             ┆ …            │
│ 3    ┆ 210    ┆ C     ┆ 210           ┆ 510          │
│ 4    ┆ 320    ┆ A     ┆ 320           ┆ 320          │
│ 6    ┆ 21     ┆ C     ┆ 21            ┆ 531          │
│ 7    ┆ 456    ┆ B     ┆ 456           ┆ 706          │
│ 1    ┆ 111    ┆ B     ┆ 0             ┆ 706          │
└──────┴────────┴───────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘
```

polars expressions seem very elegant generally, hoping there's something I am missing.

Comment: You can do it in a single step: `pl.when().then().otherwise(0).cum_sum().over()` - but I'm not sure if that is what you're asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jqurious, a single [`pl.DataFrame.with_columns`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html) call can be used to compute the conditional cumulative sum.

Moreover, the conditional amount can be computed without a `pl.when().then().otherwise()` construct, by multiplying the amount with the condition.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("amount") * (pl.col("days") > 2)).cum_sum().over("group").alias("group_sum")
    )
)
```